# записать с помощью LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

Здравствуйте, как записать следующий код с помощью LINQ:

```
DateTime limit = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes((-1) * Properties.Settings.Default.minDeleteOlderRecords);
if (!m_List.Any() == true)
{
    this.m_List.AddRange(insert);
}
else
{
    foreach (OktellChainCommutation ins in insert)
    {
        foreach (OktellChainCommutation m in m_List)
        {
            if (ins.ChainId == m.ChainId)
            {
                //  ClientNumber 
                //  CallTimeStart
                m.CallTimeEnd = ins.CallTimeEnd;
                // FirstNumber 
                m.LastNumber = ins.LastNumber;
                // CallTypeId 
                // InputTime 
                m.Commutation = ins.Commutation;
            }
        }
    }
}
this.m_List.RemoveAll(x => x.InputTime < limit);
```

Comment: а зачем его записывать с помощью linq?

Comment: а ещё унарный минус существует

Comment: Grundy, задача так поставлена

Comment: в данном случае, так как меняется элементы коллекции - linq здесь не нужен, так как в нем _нет_ методов для этого.

Comment: стоит добавить описание _что делает_ приведенный код

Comment: Этот код обновляет список m_List значениями из списка insert

Comment: Ну что есть у кого идеи?

Comment: если он **обновляет** - то linq тут не поможет. Кроме того, стоит подробнее описать что происходит, а не просто _обновляет_, в самом вопросе.

Comment: а так же, с чем у вас возникли проблемы при переписывании этого примера с помощью linq? что тут имеется ввиду под `linq`?

Comment: кроме того: в linq **нет** метода `ForEach`, но он есть в классе `List<T>`. Так какой в итоге результат ожидается?

Comment: foreach можно заменить на конструкцию типа           // this.m_List.AddRange(insert.Where(x => this.m_List.Any(y => y.ChainId == x.ChainId) == true));

                var list = m_List.Join(insert, o => o.ChainId, i => i.ChainId, (o, i) => new { Exists = o, Inserted = i });
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    item.Exists.CallTimeEnd = item.Inserted.CallTimeEnd;
                    item.Exists.LastNumber = item.Inserted.LastNumber;
                    item.Exists.Commutation = item.Inserted.Commutation;
                }

Comment: как здесь добавлять код?

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка "Править"

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov: «задача так поставлена» — это вовсе не аргумент. Если вы программист, вы должны сами уметь обосновать нужность или ненужность того или иного подхода вашему начальству.

Answer (score 3):

Если `ID` уникальные, то ветку `else` можно переписать так:

```
  foreach (OktellChainCommutation ins in insert)
  {
    var m = m_List.FirstOrDefault(l => l.ChainId == ins.ChainId);
    if (m == null)
      continue;

    m.CallTimeEnd = ins.CallTimeEnd;
    m.LastNumber = ins.LastNumber;
    m.Commutation = ins.Commutation;
  }
```

Что-то другое переводить на `Linq` - смысла мало, да и скорее всего придётся писать свои методы расширений, чтобы работало, как вам надо.